# Multidimensional arrays replacing values

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array

When I print my field it works but when I change a value the array seems to get reset. I think I'm declaring my string `veld[10][11]` on the wrong place but I'm not shure.
Also got veld as an attribute of my class `speelveld.h`
thanks

```
    #include "speelveld.h"
    #include "Schip.h"
    void spelbord::printVeld(){
        //spelbord::zetBoot();
        string veld[10][11]= {
            { "A", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " " },
            { "B", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " " },
            { "C", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " " },
            { "D", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " " },
            { "E", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " " },
            { "F", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " " },
            { "G", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " " },
            { "H", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " " },
            { "I", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " " },
            { "J", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " ", " " }
        };

        cout << "  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10" << endl;
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++){
            cout << " +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+" << endl;
            for (int j = 0; j < 11; j++){
                cout << veld[i][j] << "|" << flush;
            }
            cout << endl;
        }
        cout << " +-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+-+" << endl;
    }
    void spelbord::zetBoot(){
        string veld[10][11];
        cout << "Wat is de eerste coordinaat van je vliegdekschip? (bv: a1) " << flush;
        cin >> vliegdekschip1;
        y = vliegdekschip1[0];
        x = vliegdekschip1[1];
        cout << y << endl;
        cout << x << endl;
        spelbord::checkpos();
    }
    void spelbord::checkpos(){
        if (y == 97){
            if (x == 49){
                veld[0][1] = "O";
                spelbord::printVeld();
            }
    {
{
```

Comment: Those opening braces in the end of your code sample look weird.

Comment: The member variable `veld` is being _shadowed_ by _local variables_ of the same name. Either choose a different name for the local variable, use `this->veld` to access the member variable, or get rid of the local variables named `veld` since they don't seem necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*For the rest of my answer, I assume that your class `spelbord` has an attribute `veld` of type `string`.*

### The problem

The problem is that you use a **local** variable in your `spelbord::printVeld` function:

```
void spelbord::printVeld()
{
    /* Initialize a 'new' local variable each time you pass here. */
    string veld[10][11] = {
        /* Initialization value. */
    }

    /* Print header. */
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 11; ++j)
            /* Refers to the variable just initialized. */
            cout << veld[i][j] << "|" << flush;
        cout << endl;
    }
    /* Print footer. */
}

void spelbord::checkpos()
{
    if (y == 97)
        if (x == 49)
        {
            /* Refers to the attribute 'veld' of the 'spelbord' object */
            veld[0][1] = "O";
            spelbord::printVeld();
        }
}
```

**To sum-up** You are always displaying a variable newly initialized. Not the one you are modifying in `spelbord::checkpos`.

### A possible solution

```
/* Constructor. Used to initialize members. */
spelbord::spelbord()
{
    /* I don't use the constructor's prefered way of initialization because your 
       initialization value is huge. */
    veld = { /* Initialization. */ };
}

/* No local variable this time. */
void spelbord::printVeld()
{
    /* Print header. */
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 11; ++j)
            /* Refers to the member of the object. */
            cout << veld[i][j] << "|" << flush;
        cout << endl;
    }
    /* Print footer. */
}

void spelbord::checkpos()
{
    /* Same as before. */
}
```

This time the member is initialized only once, when the object is built, and you modify and display this member.